# ScrollView error in Xcode 4.5

Tags: xcode, scrollview

To make my scroll view scroll, i need to check the box "bounce vertically". But when i make it, while scrolling the page. The page automatically scrolls itself back to first state if i dont keep my finger holded on the screen. Please help me.

Comment: you should set the content size of your scrollview to something larger than the view itself.

Answer (score 0):

uncheck the box bounce vertically and check the box bounces. on the scroll view section of the IB right on the top check the first three boxes. show vertical... show horizontal.... scrolling enabled.

that should do the trick. let me know if this works.
adrian